# Reordering blocks without moving them from their original block

Tags: magento2, layout

I'm attempting to reorder some blocks `store.menu` and `store.links` which are within the block `navigation.sections` like this:

vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="navigation.sections" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/sections.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="group_name" xsi:type="string">navigation-sections</argument>
                <argument name="group_css" xsi:type="string">nav-sections</argument>
            </arguments>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.menu" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Menu</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="store.links" group="navigation-sections">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Account</argument>
                    <argument name="use_force" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
                    <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<!-- Account links -->]]></argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
```

I want to put `store.links` before `store.menu`. To do this I've created my own default.xml  at app/design/frontend/Matt/New/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml which contains:

```
<move element="store.links" destination="navigation.sections" before="-"/>
<move element="store.menu" destination="navigation.sections" after="-"/>
```

I know that the layout file is working as I'm able to remove these blocks but for some reason the block aren't moving the html output is still:

```
<div class="section-item-content nav-sections-item-content" id="store.menu">
<div class="section-item-content nav-sections-item-content" id="store.links">
```

I can't understand why the blocks won't reorder?